# handler are not working after hosting,i am using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-config

how to add handler in web.config,my handler name is image handler.
after hosting handler are not working.

this my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    <dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.6.5.0" newVersion="6.6.5.0" />
   <codeBase version="6.6.5.0" href="bin\Assembly\6.6.5\MySql.Data.dll"/>
   <codeBase version="6.7.4.0" href="bin\MySql.Data.dll"/>
</dependentAssembly>
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>

  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>   
</configuration>
```

Comment: can you please show us your `web.config` and handler signature along with mention which IIS version are you using

Comment: webconfig are shown above.i am hosting in hostgator server

Answer (score 1):

You can register your handler in your web.config inside the `system.web` section.

```
<system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="HandlerName" type="Namespace.HandlerClassName"/>
    </httpModules>

    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*.htm" verb="*" type="Namespace.HtmlFileHandler, Namespace"/>
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
```